# Hibernate Mapping association to Map

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

How does hibernate's @OneToMany association works with type java.util.Map? I do use @MapKey as well.

Does it first loads the query resultSet and travers through to create associated objects in ?

for example;
I have an entity Car
I have another entity CarFeatures

Car has a `@OneToMany, FetchType.LAZY` relation to `CarFeatures @JoinColumn("carId")`. Also includes a feature key with annotation `@MapKey("KEY")`

When I want to list all the Cars on a screen with some features in the list as well. I am generating the query with JOIN FETCH to select all features associated to car.

Checked the query and it seems the query is selecting `car.* and carfeature.*` from car joined with carfeatures.

But when the number of cars list is huge; It took too much to load the result set.

that's why I am trying to understand what's going on behind the scene ? as far as I can follow;

1. Hibernate fires the query.
2. Hibernate fetches the resultSet each row in the result set contains car and its "one" feature. Means if a car has 20 features. There will be 20 rows per car in the result set.
3. Then hibernate creates the Car objects including Map. While doing this hibernate traverse through the resultSet and puts each CarFeature with the key value.

Is my understanding correct ? If so, how can I select cars and their features effectively ?

One thing I plan to do is; skip the features table and create a column of Varchar to marshall/unmarshall the features as list manually.

Answer (score 0):

> How does hibernate's @OneToMany association works with type java.util.Map? I do use @MapKey as well.

Hibernate loads all `@OneToMany` associations in the same way, no matter the collection type.

> Does it first loads the query resultSet and travers through to create associated objects in ?

Yes, that's right.

> But when the number of cars list is huge; It took too much to load the result set.

That's because you didn't use pagination.

> Checked the query and it seems the query is selecting car.* and carfeature.* from car joined with carfeatures.

Yes, that's exactly what JOIN FETCH does. It does the join and projects everything from the parent and child associations being fetched.

> Hibernate fetches the resultSet each row in the result set contains car and its "one" feature. Means if a car has 20 features. There will be 20 rows per car in the result set.

Yes. If you have N cars and each car has M features, then the result set will contain N x M records.

> Is my understanding correct ? If so, how can I select cars and their features effectively ?

Of course, there is a way. Just use pagination, as explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/).

> One thing I plan to do is; skip the features table and create a column of Varchar to marshall/unmarshall the features as list manually.

That sounds like a hack that's not needed. Just use pagination and don't denormalize your schema just for a single query that didn't use pagination and, for this reason, was, of course, slow.

Comment: Well thanks for great answer again and also for the link to your article. But in this project which has tons of work done already; I have no chance but to go with the way you call. Hack. My only question; is it possible to use your type utility for json conversion towards a column (varchar). Since the DB version is not supporting JSON column type.

Comment: If you want to store JSON data in a VARCHAR, just use a `String` entity attribute and store the JSON string representation.

Comment: back to ancient ages. but that's what it has to be done now. I am always planning to include a reusable and as generic as it can be -which is not now-. In the end this is not a product but a solution and customer specific

Comment: If it's customer-specific, then there's nothing to worry about. If it were a product, then you'd have to write your own custom type that manages to save the JSON to either VARCHAR or JSON-specific columns. If you study the `hibrnate-types` project, you'll figure out how to do that.

Comment: thanks! going through this one;

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/